# Eigen MatrixXd as return type

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a templated matrix library called `CMatrix` which interfaces with Eigen library for some functions. In order to switch between libraries I have a simple function:

```
template <typename T>
MatrixXd CMatrix<T>::ToMatrixXd()
{
    const int nrow=m_row;
    const int ncol=m_column;
    MatrixXd matrixXd(nrow,ncol);
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<nrow;i++)
        for(unsigned int j=0;j<ncol;j++)
            matrixXd(i,j)=GetCellValue(i,j);

    return matrixXd;
}
```

Here the typename T is atomic types such as double, float...

I call this function in another function as:

```
 MatrixXd eigMat=m.ToMatrixXd();
```

I get the following error message:

`const math::CMatrix <double> as 'this' argument of 'Eigen::MatrixXd math::CMatrix<T>::ToMatrixXd() [with T = double; Eigen::MatrixXd = Eigen::Matrix <double, -1, -1>] discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]`

It seems that number of rows and columns stay as negative which does not make sense. I tried:

```
MatrixXd eigMat(nrow,ncolumn) //both nrow and ncolumn positive
eigMat=m.ToMatrixXd();
```

I still get the above-mentioned error message. What could be going on wrong?

Comment: ` MatrixXd eigMat=m.ToMatrixXd();` where do you make `m`?

Comment: Why your code works even after returning a local variable? "MatrixXd matrixXd''. Can somebody explain why this code is correct.

Comment: It is not a locally created pointer, just a local variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`**const** math::CMatrix <double> as 'this' argument`

It seems that the `m` in `MatrixXd eigMat=m.ToMatrixXd();` is `const` but 
`template <typename T> MatrixXd CMatrix<T>::ToMatrixXd()` is not a `const` method.

Comment: Thanks, indeed very nice catch! I always put the `const` identifier but in this case completely forgot and was led in a different direction with rows and columns being negative in the error message.